# If $x_0 \geq 2$ and $x_n = 2+ \sqrt{x_{n-1} -2}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $x_n\to 2$ or $x_n\to 3$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'd appreciate if you could please check to see if my proof is OK. I'm concerned that it's incomplete for the reason following under the proof.

> Proof:
>
> Since $x_0 \geq 2$, $x_1 = 2+\sqrt{x_0-2}\geq 2+\sqrt{2-2}=2 >1$. Thus $x_n \geq 2$ for all $n$. Also, $x_n -2 =\sqrt{x_{n-1}-2}\le 1$, which implies that $x_n - 2 \geq x_{n-1}-2\iff x_n \ge x_{n-1}$, so $x_n$ is an increasing sequence which is bounded below. By the Monotone Convergence Theorem, $L:=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_n$ exists.
>
> Case (i): ($2\le x_0 < 3$). Since $x_n \ge 2, L=2$.
>
> Case (ii): ($x_0 \ge 3$). $x_1 \ge 2+\sqrt{3-2}=3$. Thus $x_n \ge 3$ for all $n$. Thus $M:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = 3$.

I'm concerned about my proof because in the last step of the proof, there should be a clear indication that the limits are $2$ or $3$. But, for iterated (recursive) sequences I only know how to use the methods of Chaos Theory. In this course, however, I need to use some other analytic methods.

Here's my guess: take $x_0 > 3 > 2$, as large as desired, and set $\varepsilon = x_0 - 2$. Then $x_1=2+\sqrt{x_0-2}=2+\sqrt{\varepsilon}=: \tilde\varepsilon$. Thus $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=2+(\tilde\varepsilon)^{1/n}=3$. But, I know, this is too heuristic...

Comment: If you have a recursion of the form $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$, and you know it's convergent, and you know that $f$ is continuous, then the sequence must  converge to a solution of the equation $x = f(x)$. In your case, $x = 2$ and $x = 3$ are the only solutions.

Comment: @Arthur: can you please indicate what theorem you're referring to?

Comment: $x_n \geq 2$ for all $n$ because it's $2$ plus something nonnegative. No need for induction.

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong on several fronts = $x_n-2\gt 1$ is definitely false, and in particular $x_n$ is _not_ a decreasing sequence for $2\lt x_n\lt 3$.

Comment: @sequence I actually don't know whether it has a name. It's not too hard to prove (say you have an $L$ with $L \neq f(L)$, be clever about your choice of an $\epsilon > 0$, and use the definition of convergence and the continuity of $f$ to show that the sequence cannot converge to $L$).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I've double-checked and I don't see how the sequence is not decreasing (I think it is, and I showed it), and also $x_n \ge 2$ for all $n$.

Comment: @sequence if $x_0=2.5$, what is $x_1$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: $2+\sqrt{1/2}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I see what you mean, and I found my typo leading to the error. Now I'm getting really puzzled. If the sequence is increasing and bounded below, how can one apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Comment: What if x_n > 3.  then $\sqrt{x_n - 2} > 1$.

Comment: If $x_0 = 3$ then all $x_n = 3$ if $x_0 < 3$ then all $x_n < 3$.  If $x_0 > 3$ then all $x_n > 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple proof: Put $a_n := x_n - 2$. Then $a_n = a_{n-1}^{1/2}$ for each $n$ and $a_0\ge 0$. Hence, inductively, $a_n = a_0^{1/2^n}$. Since $\sqrt[n]{a}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ if $a > 0$ we get that $a_n\to 1$ if $a_0 > 0$ and $a_n = 0$ for all $n$ if $a_0 = 0$. In other words, $x_n\to 3$ if $x_0 > 2$ and $x_n = 2$ for all $n$ if $x_0 = 2$.

EDIT: This also shows that $(x_n)$ cannot be decreasing if $2 < x_0 < 3$. In fact, it is increasing in this case. For $x_0\ge 3$ it is decreasing.

Comment: It is actually said in the problem that one should use the Monotone Convergence Theorem in this problem. But now I'm getting upset because this theorem only applies when $x\ge 3$. And this theorem doesn't apply to the other case.

Comment: If $a_n = 0$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} = 0^{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} 1/n} = 0^0$, which is indeterminate.

Comment: Why this? It is also monotone when $2 < x_0 < 3$, but increasing then.

Comment: @sequence: Come on... If $a_0 = 0$ then $a_n = 0$ for each $n$, so $\lim a_n = 0$.

Comment: Yes, it is monotone, but it's not bounded above. But the theorem only applies to increasing sequences bounded above and decreasing sequences bounded below.

Comment: Of course it is bounded above since it converges. It is bounded by $3$.

Comment: The thing is that $a_n$ does not completely reflect the nature of $x_n$. In other words, $x_n \ne 2 + a_{n-1}^{1/2}$.

Comment: It does completely. It is $x_n$ shifted to the left by $2$. That's all. So, it increases/decreases when $x_n$ does and vice versa. It is bounded above/below by $c$ if and only if $x_n$ is bounded above/below by $c+2$.

Comment: You're right @FriedrichPhilipp. Your method is good I think. But, unfortunately, I think that I can't use this method since it's said that one needs to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem, and I have no idea how to use it to for the case when $x_0 < 3$ and why one has to use it for the other case, unless one just wants to show that the sequence converges to something, but not exactly to what it converges. On the other hand, if one wants to show what it converges to then there's no need in this theorem...

Comment: Indeed. I would write that I do not see a reason to use this theorem since it does not provide the limit.